# MySQL: Errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create these tables and I've got this error

> Error Code: 1005. Can't create table
>   `estadisticas`.`tbl008_phase_competition` (errno: 150 "Foreign key
>   constraint is incorrectly formed")

When I try to create tbl008_phase_competition ...

```
create table if not exists `tbl015_seasons` (
    `id` smallint(4) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    `id_competition` smallint(2) unsigned not null,
    `description` varchar(100) not null,
    primary key(`id`),
    foreign key (`id_competition`) references `tbl001_competition` (`id`) 
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

create table if not exists `tbl012_phase` (
    `id` smallint(4) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(100) not null,
    primary key (`id`) 
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

create table if not exists `tbl008_phase_competition` (
    `id_season` smallint(4) unsigned not null,
    `id_phase` smallint(4) unsigned not null,
    `year` int unsigned not null,
    primary key (`id_season`, `id_phase`),
    foreign key (`id_season`) references `tbl015_seasons` (`id`),
    foreign key (`id_phase`) references `tbl012_phase` (`id`) 
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're adding `Help me, please!!! Thanks in advance!!!` to all of your posts. Please don't - we know you need help, so this is just begging and pleading, which may earn you downvotes. We tend to trim this sort of material out, so if you can avoid it, you will be giving volunteer editors less work to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please don not declare primary key in this table and check :

```
create table if not exists `tbl008_phase_competition` (
    `id_season` smallint(4) unsigned not null,
    `id_phase` smallint(4) unsigned not null,
    `year` int unsigned not null,
    primary key (`id_season`, `id_phase`), // remove this line
    foreign key (`id_season`) references `tbl015_seasons` (`id`),
    foreign key (`id_phase`) references `tbl012_phase` (`id`) 
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Hi!!! I have remove that line and it doesn't work. I've got the same error. I don't understand anything :( Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `estadisticas`.`tbl008_phase_competition` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")